# How to fill blank while using GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, rollup

I have a table with id, desc, quantity. I used GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP to get the subTotal in the result.
Here is [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d611d/77)

In the result i want to know how to make the "description" column blank for the row created by roll up

In my actual scenario i have other columns also, but rolled up only on one column. So other columns should be empty.

My Result should be like below.

```
COALESCE(ID,'TOTAL')    DESCRIPTION                 SUM

1                       Chocolate Chip Cookies      17
2                       Oatmeal Cookies             33
3                       Snaker Cookies              49
TOTAL                                               99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT COALESCE(id,'TOTAL'),
       (case when id is null then null else description end) as description,
       sum(qty) AS SUM
FROM item
group by id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT c.printable_name AS 'Country', count(*) AS '#' 
FROM registrations r 
INNER JOIN country c ON r.country = c.country_id 
GROUP BY country

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.